# NSMenu initializer or didLoad equivalent?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm trying to build a menubar application on OS X with the NSMenu being shown when the menubar icon is clicked having a custom amount of NSMenuItems. The amount is specified in a settings window and I thought the best way of carrying this number over would be to save it to NSUserDefaults and sending a NSNotificationCenter notification when the value has changed, so the controller in charge of setting up and holding the data for the NSMenu can load this value from the defaults when the notification is received.

The problem I'm experiencing here though is that I'm unsure how to tell the menu controller to subscribe to the notifications. Since I just subclassed NSMenu I don't really have an initializer where this can be done. Or an equivalent to a didLoad method that NSWindowControllers have.

Another option would be to maybe have the menu controller be a singleton and speak directly to that without going through the notification center. Or have a reference to it in the app delegate which would amount to the same thing here.

Or maybe I'm overthinking this entirely and there's an easier way of working with this?

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `NSMenu` has an initializer. All classes do.

Probably, you instantiated your menu in a NIB. In that case, loading the NIB will initialize the menu by calling `-initWithCoder:`, which `NSMenu` implements as part of adopting the `NSCoding` protocol.

If you're instantiating the menu in code, then you must be calling an initializer as part of that (you call `[[NSMenu alloc] init...]`, where `init...` is some specific initializer).

Your scheme with notifications should work fine.

You could also have your app controller mediate between your settings window and the menu. It would have an outlet to the menu so it could call any appropriate methods, including ones added by your subclass.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow failed to realize that the init(coder:) initializer would be called by the NIB. Makes a lot of sense and solved my problem :)